# How can I make a integer for every name in a txt file?

Tags: c++, sorting, text-files

I have a text file with content like this: `Bill, 89 Alex, 64  Dan, 29`, which represents the names of some students and their note.
I want to sort them ascending by note, and my idea is to make an integer for every name, for example: `int dan = 29;` so further I can sort them, but I have no idea how to assign a integer for this names from the text file.
Hope you can help because is the first time I make a little bit more complex program. Thank you!

Comment: Your names are data, not code.

Comment: sort them by what? name? note?

Comment: i want to sort them by note, thats why i want to make them integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that in C++ (as in C) you have to define all your variables *in compile time*, i.e. when you write your code. And in your example you have text file with arbitrary count of lines, so you dont really know about it's content when you write code. This is why you cannot have very own *variable* for every line of your file.
So, if you need to store *information* about every line of your file, you can do this. First, you define format in which your *information* (i.e. string with name + integer) will be stored. This is the place where you most likely will need `struct` or something like that. `struct` and `class` are the way to agregate diffirent variables in one structure (essentially, they are more than just that, but that's not the point at the moment). If you wrote smth like

```
struct Data {
  std::string name;
  int ratio;
};
```

that means that you just defined data type called Data, that have fields "name" and "ratio". So you can use it like this:

```
Data d;
d.name = "Ben";
d.ratio = 42;
```

After this, you need some entity that can let you to store many of this Data entries. For example, you could use arrays. Imagine you will use static array here:

```
const std::size_t lineCount = getLineCount();
Data data_array[lineCount]; //Will not compile, since you cannot use variables as static arrays's size
for( std::size_t i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i ) {
  data_array[i].name = readName();
  data_array[i].ratio = readRatio();
}
```

Problem here, as you can see, is that you cannot know line count of your textfile when you write code. So you can you dynamic arrays with this code:

```
const std::size_t lineCount = getLineCount();
Data* data_array = new Data[lineCount];
for( std::size_t i = 0; i < lineCount; ++i ) {
  data_array[i].name = readName();
  data_array[i].ratio = readRatio();
}
delete[] data_array;
```

This will work, provided you somehow managed to know count of lines if your file before actual work is done, which is not the point usually.

Also raw dynamic arrays are not really nice to use because of that new/delete function pair you have to worry about. So, here in action come classes called **containers** from Standart Template Library. This classes provides you way to just insert data in it, and operate with this data in many ways. This is the classes "map", "unordered_map", "multimap", "vector" and others from former answers. Easiest of them to understand is vector, and you can read about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). Others (say'd, [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)) should fit better to your task.

Finally, to sort array (or container) of such data, you can use functions called **algorithms** from Standart Template Library. They provide generic way to operate on data in the way you need.
You can read more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/).

Not sure I need to say more here, explore links, continue your studies, good luck!

Comment: I want to ask you something more: how can i implement now reading from file into that code, because you just told me the main algorithm. I want to know how to connect it to the .txt file...

Comment: @Issue429 Well, as you said in comment below, you have learned working with text files. There is two main ways to do this: C language itself presents [FILE](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/) handle object and functions to work with it. C++ introduces object-oriented approach called [stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/). Use one your teacher (if some) wants you to use. Links will probably help you to investigate more.

Comment: i am a self techer, so i do not have a techer

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a more clever way to do this but since you're a beginner here's what I suggest:

Use a [`std::multimap<int, std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) to serve as a lookup table for a name (stored as a `std::string`) given the `int` note. You want a `std::multimap` instead of a `std::map` in case some names have the same `int` value. Separately, store all the numbers in a `std::vector<int>` and call [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort the `std::vector<int>`. Now they're sorted, and you can use [`std::multimap::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/find) to look up the name(s) associated with each `int` value.

Comment: Simply iterating the multimap should give the notes in order, won't it?  "The fundamental property of iterators of associative containers is that they iterate through the containers in the non-descending order of keys where non-descending is deﬁned by the comparison that was used to construct them."

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::unordered_map<string, int>`.

//Usage:

```
std::unordered_map<string, int> content;
//open file;
while(/*not end of file*/){
   std::string name;
   int mark;
   file>>name>>mark;
   name.erase(name.end()-1);
   content[name]=mark;
}
//close file;
```

Comment: Why unordered?  He wants them sorted.

Comment: What's the difference between `map` and `unordered_map`?

Comment: `map`... orders its elements. Heh. Most commonly implemented as a RB-tree, whereas `unordered_map` is a hashtable.

Comment: please try to explain because, as i said, i am a beginner

Comment: @Ben he wants them sorted by value, not by key.

Comment: can you give me a certain example for //read string name and int mark from file;
   content[name]=mark;

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: Then make `int` the key, so it can be sorted by key.

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure if `std::map` can deal with few elements with same key... I'm not so familiar with maps, so I'll make this answer community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct name_and_mark{
    std::string name;
    int mark;
    bool operator<(name_and_mark &second){
        return mark<second.mark;
    }
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &stream, name_and_mark &data){
    stream>>data.name>>data.mark;
    data.name.erase(data.name.end()-1);
    return stream;
}

std::forward_list<name_and_mark> content;
//open file;
while(/*not end of file*/){
    name_and_mark temp;
    file>>temp;
    content.push_front(temp);
}
//close file;
content.sort();
```

//To check it out:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, name_and_mark &data){
    stream<<data.name<<", "<<data.mark<<'\n';
    return stream;
}

for(auto &i:content)
    std::cout<<i;
```

Comment: since i start with using namespace std, is that std usefull?

Comment: When you write `using namespace std` before this code, you can skip every `std::`.

Comment: what is the last for statement doing?

Comment: It prints to the _stdout_ (usually console) `content`'s content.